# Excel VBA - Compare two Columns in two different sheets then copy/paste - speed - It takes over an hour

Tags: vba, excel

Here an absolute beginner at any form of coding, this is the first time ever I try to use VBA.

I have managed after a week and a half of searching and testing and learning to reach the below posted code and I have hit a WALL (and I'm not even done yet!)

What I am trying to achieve:

Compare the data in sheet1 with the data in sheet2 found in Columns K respectively A (there are ca. 55.000 rows in K and 2500 in A) the data might repeat itself as these are product codes and it's ok as at the end of this I want to be able to see which ones have expired.

so .. If K = A then it has to copy adjacent values found in Sheet2 - columns O, P & Q and Paste them in Sheet2 - Columns O, P & Q and if no match is found then right not found. In the Example below I have only tried to copy Q, it would probably take forever if I tried adding O & P.

(Note: I have found this code in one of the forms here and used it after trying different other ways with select/ Copy/ Paste etc. but none have worked)

Later I would like to try adding another column in Sheet1 and based on the Date which will be copied to Sheet1 and into column P populate it with Expired or Soon to be expired depending on the case, but this is an entire different story and I haven't even begun thinking how to do it.

The problem is that my current code takes over an hour and it's still not finished yet while I am writing this!!! And I do not understand where have I gone wrong ....

```
Dim lastRow1 As Long
Dim lastRow2 As Long
Dim tempVal As String



lastRow1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
lastRow2 = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).Row

For sRow = 2 To lastRow1
        tempVal = Sheets("MatCode").Cells(sRow, "A").Text
For tRow = 2 To lastRow2
            If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(tRow, "K") = tempVal Then
            Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(tRow, "Q") = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(sRow, "Q")
            End If

    Next tRow
    Next sRow

Dim match As Boolean
'now if no match was found, then put NO MATCH in cell
    For lRow = 2 To lastRow2
        match = False
        tempVal = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(lRow, "K").Text

For sRow = 2 To lastRow1
            If Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(sRow, "A") = tempVal Then
                match = True
            End If
        Next sRow
If match = False Then
            Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(lRow, "Q") = "NO MATCH"
        End If
    Next lRow
End Sub
```

I have also used:

```
With Application
    .AskToUpdateLinks = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .DisplayAlerts = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With
```

To make sure nothing stands in the way.

Please Help!

Comment: It will tend to take time as the data is too large

Comment: Look into `Range.Find` instead of looping. Get rid of nested loops if at all possible. Don't leave the loop going unnecessarily after a match has been found. Load your data into an array before making the comparison. Generally, have a look at this [ozgrid page](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/SpeedingUpVBACode.htm) for an introduction.

Comment: You're a beginner, so it will be very difficult to properly improve the process. That said, I don't believe in learning bad habits purely for the sake of not wanting to learn good habits. I strongly recommend learning arrays and dictionaries. It takes a bit at first, but if you can learn them, this will be a breeze. That said, at the very least, put an `Exit For` in your loops when a `Match` condition is met. Be sure to qualify your ranges as well (they currently rely on the implicit `ActiveWorkbook` which is prone to failure).

Comment: 1) I looked into `Range.Find` and it seems much easier indeed and I will test it as well! For now it works with the lovely solution provided by Mooseman.

Comment: 2) I am indeed a more than a beginner at this and thank you for the advice! I do not have a problem with wanting to learn the good habits, though it has been confusing which ones are which, I have start with this a little over two weeks ago with no background whatsoever and had to find a way two make it work in two weeks to have something to show to the management. I do not know if I will be doing more of this in the future, but it has been quite a ride, I felt at times that I should just stop torturing myself but I have really enjoyed it the same time  :)))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will loop through rows to match column A on Sheet1 with column K on sheet2.  On a non-match "No Match" will be put in Sheet1 column Q.
On a match Sheet2 columns O,P and Q will be copied to Sheet1 columns O,P and Q.
This took about 10 seconds to run for over 12k in column A and over 2500 in column K.

```
Sub match_columns()
Dim I, total, fRow As Integer
Dim found As Range

total = Sheets(1).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For I = 1 To total
    answer1 = Worksheets(1).Range("A" & I).Value
 Set found = Sheets(2).Columns("K:K").Find(what:=answer1) 'finds a match
If found Is Nothing Then   
    Worksheets(1).Range("Q" & I).Value = "NO MATCH"
Else
    fRow = Sheets(2).Columns("K:K").Find(what:=answer1).Row
    Worksheets(1).Range("O" & I).Value = Worksheets(2).Range("O" & fRow).Value
    Worksheets(1).Range("P" & I).Value = Worksheets(2).Range("P" & fRow).Value
    Worksheets(1).Range("Q" & I).Value = Worksheets(2).Range("Q" & fRow).Value
 End If
Next I


End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! Your answer was truly enlightening!

Answer (score 2):

Thank you again @Mooseman for providing the solution!

I only had to change Range A with K, at first even so I was not able to make it work as it copied only the first line. I already had some code which opened the Worksheets and copied them to a new Worksheet/added new columns ..etc., to be SavedAs for later use, and it seems that because of this your code was not able to loop properly (not sure how to explain this) in any case at the end of the open / save workbooks ..etc I have introduced a [Call Sub Procedure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/calling-sub-and-function-procedures)  which worked like a charm!

Also, introduced two extra lines to properly format columns O and P as Date.

I am sure it could have looked better than this, but so far it works!

And thank you to everyone who provided me with suggestions, there is still a lot to learn and I am planning to test other ways just for the sake of learning, but I needed this to work now.

```
Sub Button1_Click()

   With Application
        .AskToUpdateLinks = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .DisplayAlerts = False
        .EnableEvents = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
   End With

'Code to Open / Save / introduce  new columns into Sheet(1)

Call match_columns
End Sub

Sub match_columns()

Dim I, total, frow As Integer
Dim found As Range

total = Sheets(1).Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
 'MsgBox (total) --> used to test if it can count/see the total number of rows

For I = 2 To total
    answer1 = Worksheets(1).Range("K" & I).Value
 Set found = Sheets(2).Columns("A:A").Find(what:=answer1) 'finds a match

If found Is Nothing Then
    Worksheets(1).Range("Q" & I).Value = "NO MATCH"
Else
    frow = Sheets(2).Columns("A:A").Find(what:=answer1).Row
    Worksheets(1).Range("O" & I).Value = Worksheets(2).Range("O" & frow).Value
    Worksheets(1).Range("P" & I).Value = Worksheets(2).Range("P" & frow).Value
    Worksheets(1).Range("Q" & I).Value = Worksheets(2).Range("Q" & frow).Value

 End If
Next I

Worksheets(1).Range("P2", "P" & total).NumberFormat = "dd.mm.yyyy"
Worksheets(1).Range("O2", "O" & total).NumberFormat = "dd.mm.yyyy"


  With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .DisplayAlerts = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .AskToUpdateLinks = True
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    End With


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This is slow because your macro is iterating through 55,000 * 2,500 rows of data, twice. That's 275,000,000 cycles.

I think the solution is to scrap the macro and use `VLOOKUP` or `Index` `Match`.

You could add this formula to cell Q2 of sheet1:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!$Q:$Q,MATCH(Sheet1!$K2,Sheet2!$A:$A,0)),"NO MATCH")
```

[image]

[image]

That is how I would do this. If you need it to be a macro, you can write a macro that just sets Sheet1 K2 to have this formula and drag the formula down.