# Copy & Paste With Multiple Condition and basing on the same value

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I'm new to VBA(coding) i just need your help on a work that i'm doing. the process is on Sheet1 we have the raw data as you can see on the attachment

[image]

we have the names on column a & orders and  column b. i just want to copy the orders which is on column b basing on the name from column a from sheet1 to sheet2 sample image on the attachment on the result

[image]

Also if  we have a name on sheet1 that is not available in sheet2 we could just ignore  or skip the order unless we added the name on sheet2. also the other condition is if we could skip a cell if it has values already we can only paste it if cells from column b on sheet2 are blank. like if john's order has been change on sheet1 from dumplings to soup. i want John to have the same first order he took earlier which is dumplings  that is saved on sheet2 earlier unless i deleted the first order. hope you guys can help appreciate your time a lot.

this is would be my current code all i need is the code to skip cells with values in sheet2 on column b

```vb
Sub Rectangle1_Click() 
Dim I, total, fRow As Integer 
Dim found As Range

total = Sheets(2).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For I = 1 To total 
answer1 = Worksheets(2).Range("A" & I).Value 
Set found = Sheets(1).Columns("A:A").Find(what:=answer1) 
If found Is Nothing Then 
Worksheets(2).Range("A" & I).Value = "" 
Else  
fRow = Sheets(1).Columns("A:A").Find(what:=answer1).Row  
Worksheets(2).Range("B" & I).Value = Worksheets(1).Range("B" & fRow).Value  
End If 
Next I

End Sub
```

Comment: Your best bet here is to start simple by just getting a small VBA routine to get a list of Customer names from your sheet and loop through them. Then add in the part of comparing to a list of names from the second sheet, before adding in the part to copy the orders. If you break up the problem you're facing into small steps, you can tackle it piece by piece. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45846212/4717755) and [this](https://www.exceltip.com/cells-ranges-rows-and-columns-in-vba/compare-2-columns-through-vba-in-microsoft-excel.html) are good places to start.

Comment: Why not just make a Pivot Table on sheet2? that way it will automatically update too

Comment: Thanks PeterT appreciate the response

Comment: Fernando J. Rivera. we actually need them as values thank you for the input sir